# Create a new Geojson polygon smaller/bigger size and the same shape from an original one in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, polygon

We need to create a polygon buffer zone - both positive and negative (bigger and smaller size polygons) from the given one of a random shape.
That could have been done if there was a functionality to create a perpendicular line of the given length to the original polygon, but I can not find such functionality in Snowflake.

Comment: How are you creating your initial polygon?

Comment: It's given to us by city authorities - we work with cities. So it can not be changed.

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear. In your question it seems to suggest that you've created already created the original polygon in Snowflake and you are asking how to create a new polygon. If that is correct, how did you create the original polygon in Snowflake?

Comment: The original polygon is a geogson in Snowflake, uploaded from the other source